# How to prevent cluster shows a different value than I have

Tags: openlayers, wfs

I have created vectors using as source `WFS` but when I zoomin/zoomout/movemap number on vector(length) changes as I have more vectors but I don't. I had another cluster for more vectors so I thought they are grouping but disabled it to test vector from WFS and error persists.

Here is my vector:

```
const approvedUsersSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
    url: function (extent) {
        return (
            'https://url/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&' +
            'version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typename=approvedUser&' +
            'outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:3857&' +
            'bbox=' +
            extent.join(',') +
            ',EPSG:3857'
        );
    },
    strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox,
});

const approvedUsersCluster = new ol.source.Cluster({
    distance: 50,
    source: approvedUsersSource
});
let styleCacheUser = {};
const approvedUsers = new ol.layer.Vector({
    title: 'Usuarios encuestados',
    source: approvedUsersCluster,
    style: function (feature) {
            let sizeUser = feature.get('features').length;
            let styleUser = styleCacheUser[sizeUser];
            if (!styleUser) {
                styleUser = new ol.style.Style({
                    image: new ol.style.Icon({
                        anchor: [0.5, 0.5],
                        size: [30, 30],
                        offset: [0, 0],
                        scale: 1,
                        src: 'assets/img/approvedUser.png'
                    }),
                    text: new ol.style.Text({
                        text: sizeUser.toString(),
                        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                            color: '#fff'
                        }),
                        font: "bold 15px sans-serif",
                        /* offsetY: +2.5 */
                    })
                });
                styleCacheUser[sizeUser] = styleUser;
            }
            return styleUser;
    }
});
```

Also tried filtering  by feature value to get in coming code from WFS but didn't work, like this :

```
let filterFeature = feature.get('features')[0].T;
if(filterFeature.startsWith("approvedUser"){
et sizeUser = feature.get('features').length;
            let styleUser = styleCacheUser[sizeUser];
            if (!styleUser) {
                styleUser = new ol.style.Style({
                    image: new ol.style.Icon({
                        anchor: [0.5,
.
.
.
}
```

If `console.log(feature.get('features'))` value duplicates when i move/zoom map

so I show 2 images, 1 on first load page and another when I move/zoom map

[image: First load]

[image: zooming]

Comment: Code looks OK, so without access to the layer source it's impossible to guess with goes wrong.

Comment: Could solve it using tile as strategy

Comment: Did you try to check if features are actually rendered twice? You could to that in the style function.

Comment: Reading a little about openlayers, features from geoserver need an `id`, I had 2 options: Create a table to set featureID or use another strategy(tile)

Comment: It sound like a cache problem then. Obviously features get cached when using bbox loading strategy and if features don't have unique IDs, they get repeated when zooming, since it's impossible to distinguish one form another.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what was happening